# Replacing search query strings to make it SEF

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I tried the below .htaccess rewrite to internally rewrite the urls and make the overall urls SEF.

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^searchword=(.*)&(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^searchword=(.*)&(.*)$ searchword=$1 [L]
```

My url is of the following form.
http://www.domain.com/?searchword=search+term&Search=&searchphrase=all&limit=50&ordering=newest&view=search&option=com_search

I want to make it of the form

http://www.domain.com/?searchword=search+term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(searchword=[^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /?%1&Search=&searchphrase=all&limit=50&ordering=newest&view=search&option=com_search [L,NE]
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(searchword=.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* /?$1&Search=&searchphrase=all&limit=50&ordering=newest&view=search&option=com_search [L,NE]

This works .. as in gives the search page but no search results..

Comment: Try updated code now. You will need `%1` not `$1` in the target.

Comment: Try adding `R` in the end i.e. `[L,NE,R]`

Comment: Good for debugging but defeats the purpose... after redirection $1  isn't part of the URL ...(i.e url is only /?&Search=&searchphrase=all&limit=50&ordering=newest&view=search&option=com_search)

Comment: Once again you are making the same mistake. See my answer above. You need to use `%1 not $1`

Comment: Kewl... Sorry about that.. I must have read it wrongly earlier.. It works perfectly now :)

Comment: one small thingy remains..
I used 
    RedirectMatch ^searchword=[^&]+(.*)$ http://domain.com/?searchword=$1 [R,NC] 
{Yes I am bad at Reg expressions.. Getting better though.. }

to redirect all old urls to the new ones.. It throws an internal Server Error :(

Comment: Didn't get your last comment. What are you trying to do with `RedirectMatch`? (It is incorrect also)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43720/discussion-between-j-d-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by adding a router.php file to your component. Take a look at http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component